# best and right way toorganize bundles in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm a little bit confused how I should organize the bundles in symfony2. In my app I'll need 3 pages:

1- Insert
2- List
3- Update

Which one could be the right and best way to organize my code?

src/cp/AddPageBundle
src/cp/EditPageBundle
src/cp/UpdatePageBundle

OR

In one bundle write 3 different controllers, each one in a different file?

OR

In one bundle, write 3 different actions in one controller file?

I'm really confused with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

In one bundle, 3 different actions in one controller. There is no need to split this functionality across bundles or controllers.

For example you can edit/list/update User with UserController (insertAction, ListAction, UpdateAction) to deal with the user and for example add another controller (CommentsController) for edit/list/update comments. The same situation can be used for your Page example (add/edit/update)

Optional way is to create folder inside controller folder so that we have even more organized code. For example for create Admin folder for controllers: Admin/ConsoleController, Admin/CategoryController, Admin/PluginController to deal with admin functionality.

Comment: Hey,thanks a lot! And just to complement, do you use the routing from app/config/routing.yml or each routing should be placed inside each bundle?

Comment: I would use individual routing inside each bundle. That way bundle works on its own (is isolated) and can be passed to other applications without loosing routes.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly I agree with TroodoN-Mike. Also you should create PageBundle with your Page entity and your fields (publish_date, title, content ect), and execute

```
app/console generate doctrine:crud PageBundle:Page
```

Symfony will generate a basic CRUD, but with your insert/list/update

Answer (score 0):

just tried this - command is:

`app/console doctrine:generate:crud --entity PageBundle:Page`

This starts up a wizard on the command line which will prompt you for any other parameters it needs.

Unfortunately only works if your primary key field is called id and has a `getID()` method.